# Can AppFabric be deployed on Windows 7?

Tags: caching, deployment, windows-7, appfabric

I wish to use AppFrbric 1.1 for data Caching in several use cases. The system requirements on the it's [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=27115) suggest that it is meant for Windows Server 2008 and above, for production environment while it can be installed for development and testing on Windows 7.

My product is web based and can be deployed in a server environment for medium sized customers but for a single user deployment, it should be deployable on a workstation running Windows 7.

So, should AppFabric be included in my solution or not? If deployed, will it have any technological implication on Windows 7 (which I suspect, not)? And whether it has any legal / compliance related implication that I need to be mindful of.

BTW, I cannot have two implementations for caching due the impact on support. If AppFabric cannot be used, then I might have to resort to a custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use it on Windows 7 (i did it).
Also, do not confuse Client Api ([Nuget Here](http://nuget.org/packages/ServerAppFabric.Client/)) with the cache service ([download here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27115)).

The System requirements are very simple to understand : on production, you will use dedicated servers for hosting the cache servicen running on Windows Server.
For development, you will certainly use Windows 7 or 8. The cache service can be installed on these System, but you will have less availability and lower perf. However, it's not so important for this environment.

Comment: Thanks for responding but I don't think you understood my question. Like you've mentioned, AppFabric service needs to be deployed on Windows Server while we can use Windows 7 or 8 as a client. My question is can I deploy even the "AppFabric SERVICE" on customer's Windows 7 workstation (i.e. in production)?

Comment: it's completely useless to do this. AppFabric is a distributed cached : it's perfect for distribute data across multiple servers for many clients. You will also troubles with maintenance because it requires specific maintenance task. Use a local cache for your app like the System.runtime.Caching.MemoryCache. Of course, you can try your idea, but you will start with a handicap

Comment: For reference of everyone I tried it on Windows 8.1 Enterprise operating system and it is not supported.